# Loop not occurring using python socket

Tags: python, loops, python-sockets

I am using my server code on a raspberry pi and my client code on my laptop. I also off the firewall on my computer. After connecting to the server, I manage to run the loop for once from the client side by keying the word "data" and when I keyed in another command it just came out of the loop. If i key in Quit it says that it have an OS error98 address already in used. May I know how to keep the loop on going ? Below I is my client.py and server.py code.

**Server.py code:**

```
import socket
import numpy as np
import encodings

HOST = '192.168.1.65'  
PORT = 65432        # Port to listen on (non-privileged ports are > 1023)
def random_data():          # ANY DATA YOU WANT TO SEND WRITE YOUR SENSOR CODE HERE

    x1 = np.random.randint(0, 55, None)         # Dummy temperature
    y1 = np.random.randint(0, 45, None)         # Dummy humidigy
    my_sensor = "{},{}".format(x1,y1)
    return my_sensor                            # return data seperated by comma
def my_server():

    with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
        print("Server Started waiting for client to connect ")
        s.bind((HOST, PORT))
        s.listen(5)
        conn, addr = s.accept()

        with conn:
            print('Connected by', addr)
            while True:

                data = conn.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')

                if str(data) == "Data":

                    print("Ok Sending data ")

                    my_data = random_data()

                    x_encoded_data = my_data.encode('utf-8')

                    conn.sendall(x_encoded_data)

                elif  str(data) == "Quit":
                    print("shutting down server ")
                    break

                else:
                    pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    while 1:
        my_server()
```

**Client.py Code:**

```
import socket
import threading
import time


HOST = '192.168.1.65'  # The server's hostname or IP address
PORT = 65432       # The port used by the server


def process_data_from_server(x):
    x1, y1 = x.split(",")
    return x1,y1

def my_client():
    threading.Timer(11, my_client).start()

    with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
        s.connect((HOST, PORT))

        my = input("Enter command ")

        my_inp = my.encode('utf-8')

        s.sendall(my_inp)

        data = s.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')

        x_temperature,y_humidity = process_data_from_server(data)

        print("Temperature {}".format(x_temperature))
        print("Humidity {}".format(y_humidity))

        s.close()
        time.sleep(5)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    while 1:
        my_client()
```

Comment: if it's not "DATA" try printing what you do get, regardless. Might help debug.

Comment: I tried other input and it shows me an error


s.bind((HOST, PORT)) 
OSError: [Errno 98] Address already in use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    address already used
```

you need to use `socket.setsockopt` to set `socket.SO_REUSEADDR` in i think both client and server.py

```
 def my_server():
    
        # with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        print("Server Started waiting for client to connect ")
        s.bind((HOST, PORT))
        s.listen(5)
        conn, addr = s.accept()
    
        with conn:
            print('Connected by', addr)
            while True:
    
                data = conn.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
                if str(data) == "Data":
                    ...
```